# Errors In JQuery Validated Contact Form

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using JQuery to validate a contact form but it's not submitting when I press the send button.  Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var nameok = 0;
    var telephoneok = 0;
    var emailok = 0;
    var messageok = 0;
    var validok = 1;
    // Name Validation
    $('#name').blur(function()
    {
        var name=$("#name").val();
        if(name.length < 1){
            nameok = 0;
        }
        else {
            nameok = 1;
        }
    });
    // Telephone Validation
    $('#telephone').blur(function()
    {
        var telephone=$("#telephone").val();
        if(telephone.length < 1){
            telephoneok = 0;
        }
        else {
        telephoneok = 1;
        }
    });
    // E-Mail Validation
    $('#email').blur(function()
    {
        var email=$("#email").val();
        if(email.length < 1){
            emailok = 0;
        }
        else {
        emailok = 1;
        }
    });
    // Message Validation
    $('#message').blur(function()
    {
        var message=$("#message").val();
        if(message.length < 1){
            messageok = 0;
        }
        else {
            messageok = 1;
        }
    });
    // Valid Validation
    $('#valid').blur(function()
    {
        var valid=$("#valid").val();
        if(valid.length > 0){
            validok = 0;
        }
        else {
            validok = 1;
        }
    });
    // Contact Validation
    if(telephoneok == 1 || emailok == 1){
        contactok = 1;
    }
    else{
        contactok = 0;
    }
    // Submit button action
    $('#submit').click(function()
    {
        if(nameok == 1 && contactok == 1 && messageok == 1 && validok == 1)
        {
            $('#submit').hide();
            $('#form').submit();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#submit').show();
        }
        return false;
    });
    //End
});
</script>
```

My form opens with:

```
<form id="form" action="mail.php" method="POST">
```

I think that the error may be with the `Contact Validation` section but I'm not sure. Any advice on how to get this working?

Comment: Post relevant html too..

Comment: we can check the error in console by clicking f12,kindly mention what error you are getting

Comment: @papsk - That's the thing, I'm not getting an error! The 'Submit' button hides but the form just doesn't post to mail.php - Also, the email/telephone do not need to be filled in for the button to hide, whereas it should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `return false`. It's being executed whether your validation passes or fails. This does not allow the form to proceed. Move it to the final else case instead, which will only tell the form that it is NOT OK to continue when one of your validators has failed.:

```
{
    $('#submit').show();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that solves the problem of sending, but the problem I have is that it's sending the form even if there is no Telephone or Email value.  I need it to recognise if there is one or the other before submitting

Comment: You are checking for contactOk before the user presses submit. You want to do this after the user presses submit.  Therefore, move your "Contact Validation" case into the submit listener before you check to see if nameok==1, etc.

Comment: Oh I forgot to ammend my question! Yeah I found that was the problem and fixed it - Cheers Noel